# Output traffic on different interfaces based on origin subnet

Tags: debian, iptables, linux-networking

This a diagram of my current network, http://s1.postimg.org/5689b415b/actual_diagram.png

**Objective**

Route 172.16.0.x/18 subnet web traffic to ADSL connection

What do you think of this approach, will it work? I can't set up a test environment at this moment.

**LAN Gateway**

```
$INTERFACE = eth1

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE \
                             -p tcp --dport 80 \
                             -j MARK --set-mark 0x1

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE \
                             -p tcp --dport 443 \
                             -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

**Internet Gateway**

Create a table web-traffic

```
echo 100 web-traffic >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Create a routing rule

```
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 table web-traffic
```

Setup the web-traffic table to route the proper way

```
ip route add default dev eth0 table web-traffic
```

Route everything else through the other interface

```
ip route add default dev eth1
```